# How can I acces to my database in localhost from android - Kivy/Python

Tags: python, android, postgresql, kivy, localhost

I'm working on a project using Kivy/Python and PostgreSql so I faced a problem I don't know how can I access to my database from android, (localhost) in laptop it works good but on android phone I don't know how can I access to localhost, I tried to deploy my app to my phone using USB cable. what I should please can someone give me an idea about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localhost is used to access the network services that are running on the host via the loopback network interface. So no other devices can connect to it.

One solution for you to be able to access your database from your phone is by enabling the database to listen on all interfaces. This can be enabled by changing postgresql.conf listen_addresses in `postgresql.conf` which allows incoming connections on all available IP interfaces.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Make sure you restart the postgres process after changing the configuration.

If your phone is on the same network then you can set the project setting to the computer IP address that is running postgres.

Comment: thank u i found that i have already listen_addresses = '*' and yes the computer and the phone are in the same network